# Хранение Токена (IdentityServer4) в базе данных (pgSQL)

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, token, identityserver4

*Мобильное приложение через IdentityServer подключается к микросервису и затем через API(s) к базе данных.
Все работает.
Кроме бага, который обнаружен (иногда), мобильное приложение по истечении валидности токена или при перезапуске Identity выдает ошибку или просит зайти заново. В следствии чего, понятно, что токен кешируется локально и иногда теряется. Я новичок, и так я это вижу*

Решение: Нужно сохранять токен в базе данных, чтобы при надобности IdentityServer мог запросить и тем самым **баг решен**✔ ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ.

В данном вопросе хотелось бы рассмотреть возможное решение для элегантности кода.
Ссылки откуда я брала информацию :

- [Документация](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/quickstarts/4_entityframework.html)
- [Изменения двух моделей, которые не имеют по умолчанию ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618235/using-identityserver4-with-custom-configration-dbcontext/48394620#48394620)

```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceFlowCodes>().HasNoKey();
    modelBuilder.Entity<PersistedGrant>().HasNoKey();
   //в моем случае не позволяло сохранить токен, поля были readOnly
```

- [Очень интересная лекция/доклад](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Y7Glw6NzLM)

над приложением я не одна работаю, и ниже прикладываю код, который я добавила уже к рабочему IdentityServer

добавила NuGet:

```cs
IdentityServer4 3.1.4
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage 3.1.4
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.4
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework 3.1.4
```

```cs
public class IdentityServer4DbContext : IPersistedGrantDbContext, IConfigurationDbContext ...
{
    public DbSet<PersistedGrant> PersistedGrants { get; set; }
     
    public DbSet<DeviceFlowCodes> DeviceFlowCodes { get; set; }
        
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
      
    public DbSet<IdentityResource> IdentityResources { get; set; }
        
    public DbSet<ApiResource> ApiResources { get; set; }


...

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(configuration.ConnectionString, o => o.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name));
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     if (modelBuilder is null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilder));

     modelBuilder.Entity("IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.DeviceFlowCodes", b =>
     {
          b.Property<string>("UserCode")
              .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
              .HasMaxLength(200);

          b.Property<string>("ClientId")
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(200);

          b.Property<DateTime>("CreationTime");

          b.Property<string>("Data")
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(50000);

          b.Property<string>("DeviceCode")
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(200);

          b.Property<DateTime?>("Expiration")
              .IsRequired();

          b.Property<string>("SubjectId")
               .HasMaxLength(200);

          b.HasKey("UserCode");

          b.HasIndex("DeviceCode")
               .IsUnique();

          b.HasIndex("UserCode")
               .IsUnique();

          b.ToTable("DeviceCodes");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity("IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.PersistedGrant", b =>
    {
         b.Property<string>("Key")
             .HasMaxLength(200);

         b.Property<string>("ClientId")
             .IsRequired()
             .HasMaxLength(200);

         b.Property<DateTime>("CreationTime");

         b.Property<string>("Data")
             .IsRequired()
             .HasMaxLength(50000);

         b.Property<DateTime?>("Expiration");

         b.Property<string>("SubjectId")
             .HasMaxLength(200);

         b.Property<string>("Type")
             .IsRequired()
             .HasMaxLength(50);

         b.HasKey("Key");

         b.HasIndex("SubjectId", "ClientId", "Type");

         b.ToTable("PersistedGrants");
     });
  }

Task<int> IPersistedGrantDbContext.SaveChangesAsync() => base.SaveChangesAsync();

public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() => base.SaveChangesAsync();
```

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...

services.AddConfigurationStore<IdentityServer4DbContext>()
        .AddOperationalStore<IdentityServer4DbContext>(options => {
            // this enables automatic token cleanup.
            options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
            options.TokenCleanupInterval = 43200; // 43200 = 12 hours. interval in seconds (default is 3600)
            });

...
}

private async void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
.....

IdentityServer4DbContext dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IdentityServer4DbContext>();
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
.....

    if (!dbContext.Clients.Any())
    {
        foreach (var client in Config.Clients)
        {
            dbContext.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
        }
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    if (!dbContext.IdentityResources.Any())
    {
        foreach (var resource in Config.Ids)
        {
            dbContext.IdentityResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
        }
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    if (!dbContext.ApiResources.Any())
    {
        foreach (var resource in Config.Apis)
        {
            dbContext.ApiResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
        }
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

затем миграция и в результате созданы таблицы с данными и токенами, при вхождении с мобильного и никаких ошибок, работает и тестировала много, перезагружала Identity пока мобильное приложение работало и наоборот, и дургими способами, которые раньше выдавали ошибку. То есть код рабочий, но вот в чем мой **вопрос** профессионалам: Та часть, где вручную set-ирую две модели (`DeviceFlowCodes, PersistedGrant`), есть ли какой то вариант создать класс отдельно как модель, так как я пыталась, но у меня не вышло, и пока я не вижу как вытащить этот код наружу из `OnModelCreating`
Хотелось бы услышать различные точки зрения и возможно замечания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Статические методы, которые позволяют проделать то же самое, и вуаля, эллегантное решение кода. Проверено, работает также и проведенно немало тестов ✔

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      if (modelBuilder is null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilder));

      ConfigurationStoreOptions configurationStoreOptions = new ConfigurationStoreOptions();
      OperationalStoreOptions operationalStoreOptions = new OperationalStoreOptions();

      modelBuilder.ConfigureClientContext(configurationStoreOptions);
      modelBuilder.ConfigureResourcesContext(configurationStoreOptions);
      modelBuilder.ConfigurePersistedGrantContext(operationalStoreOptions);
}
```